# Convert bytes3 to string in Solidity

Tags: string, solidity

I need to create function to convert byte3 to string.
On my contract, data is saved into a state variable.

I want to convert content of variable for user.

This is my function:

```
function convertByteToString() public view returns(string memory){
    string memory result = string(symbol);
    return result;
}
```

but I get a compiler error:

> TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes3" to "string memory".

How can this error be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert **bytes3** to **string** you must use the `abi.encodePacked(bytes3 parameter)` and this result you must convert it into a string.

Change your function with this:

```
function convertByteToString(bytes3 symbol) public view returns(string memory){
  string memory result = string(abi.encodePacked(symbol));
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only a dynamic-length byte array (Solidity type `bytes`) can be typecasted to a string, but you're passing a fixed-length byte array (Solidity type `bytes3`).

Use `abi.encode()` to convert the `bytes3` to `bytes`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    bytes3 symbol = 0x455448; // hex-encoded ASCII value of "ETH"

    function convertByteToString() public view returns(string memory){
        string memory result = string(abi.encode(symbol));
        return result;
    }
}
```